# I add LDAP AD to WP with the help of plugin, but after changes in AD in WP I have still old users

Tags: wordpress, active-directory, ldap

I added LDAP AD to Wordpress and the plugin makes it once. What if I want to check the status or what if the user will be deleted from AD, how can I synchronize it or check the user, delete automatically in WP by any plugin?

I have WPMU Ldap Authentication plugin,
Simple WordPress Membership plugin, Active Directory Integration for Intranet sites plugin.

Comment: You would need to schedule a job that goes through every user in Wordpress and verify they still exist in AD. I know AD, but I don't know Wordpress, so I can't help with that.

Comment: Thnk you. I used another plugin and now it works. It is not creating a members so I do not need to do extra work.